# php : find the last element index in multi dimension array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, indexing

As mentioned, how do i get the last element index , for example the position of 11 in this $a  ?

```
$a[0][0] = 0; 
$a[0][1] = 1; 
$a[0][2] = 2; 
$a[1][0] = 3; 
$a[1][1] = 4; 
$a[1][2] = 5; 
$a[2][3] = 6; 
$a[2][4] = 7; 
$a[2][5] = 8; 
$a[3][0] = 9; 
$a[4][0] = 10; 
$a[4][1] = 11;
enter code here
```

i will like to receive x = 1, y = 4

Comment: It's doesn't look like PHP code

Comment: how about in this way ?
$a[0][0] = 0;
  $a[0][1] = 1;
  $a[0][2] = 2;
  $a[1][0] = 3;
  $a[1][1] = 4;
  $a[1][2] = 5;
  $a[2][3] = 6;
  $a[2][4] = 7;
  $a[2][5] = 8;
  $a[3][0] = 9;
  $a[4][0] = 10;
  $a[4][1] = 11;

Comment: how about editing your question with what your actully using.

Comment: @Dagon (answer->question typo?)

Comment: @AlexLunix i have no idea what you are talking about :-)

Comment: Will your array has user-defined keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$a=array(0=>array(),1=>array(),2=>array(),3=>array(),4=>array());
$a[0][0] = 0; 
$a[0][1] = 1; 
$a[0][2] = 2; 
$a[1][0] = 3; 
$a[1][1] = 4; 
$a[1][2] = 5; 
$a[2][3] = 6; 
$a[2][4] = 7; 
$a[2][5] = 8; 
$a[3][0] = 9; 
$a[4][0] = 10; 
$a[4][1] = 11;
end($a);
$x=key($a);
echo "x=$x ";
end($a[$x]);
echo "y=".key($a[$x]);
```

This will output:

```
x=4 y=1
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/YfBFWznR

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get last array value of `11` then you can simple use `end()` array function

```
echo end(end($a));
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.org/fSsHJYTI

**Full code:**

```
 <?php

    $a[0][0] = 0; 
    $a[0][1] = 1; 
    $a[0][2] = 2; 
    $a[1][0] = 3; 
    $a[1][1] = 4; 
    $a[1][2] = 5; 
    $a[2][3] = 6; 
    $a[2][4] = 7; 
    $a[2][5] = 8; 
    $a[3][0] = 9; 
    $a[4][0] = 10; 
    $a[4][1] = 11;

    echo end(end($a));

 ?>
```

Comment: i mean to get the index of 11 in this multidimension array

Comment: I forgot this function very well

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array(0,1,2),
    array(3,4,5,6,7,8),
    array(9),
    array(10,11),
);
var_dump($a[count($a)-1][count($a[count($a)-1])-1]);
```

Comment: hmm .. i mean to get the index of 11, tat mean i will like to receive x = 1, y = 4

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over the array, find the highest entry, then store the current loop counters as `$highest_i` or `$highest_j`.

More lazy would be to convert the array first:

```
foreach ($array as $i=>$sub) {
   foreach ($sub as $j=>$value) {
      $by_value[$value] = array($i, $j);
   }
}
```

Then sort that:

```
ksort($by_value);
```

Which will give you the coordinates in the first entry:

```
print_r(reset($by_value));
```

As:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1
)
```